# Need help on RegEx

Tags: .net, regex

I need a help with RegEx for .NET language:

For example I have the following set of data in four different files:

```
START;MEG;DAT01-01;DAT02-10;100001-1001;SER1"END;MEG;5-0-2-1"

START;MEG;DAT03-01;DAT02;100001-1001;SER1"END;MEG;5-0-32-1"

START;MEG;DATA05;DAT02;100001-1001;SER1"END;MEG;5-0-2-21"

START;MEG;DATA500A-01;DAT02;100001-1001;SER1"END;MEG;5-0-2-1"
```

And I need to capture always third column value separated by `;` but before `-`, hence the result I should get from each of the above file is

```
DAT01
DAT03
DATA05
DATA5001A
```

Comment: Is it for a Nintex workflow? Please precise, and let know what you tried. Do you have access to direct .NET code (C#, VB.NET, etc.)? And just to double sure: is the input a string with multiple linebreaks?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `I have the following set of data in four different files`, that means default string doesn't have linebreak (1 line per file).

Comment: Given `START;MEG;` is always there, `(?<=START;MEG;).*?(?=[;-])` should work: https://regex101.com/r/6Wr1ru/3

Comment: @nozzleman Thanks. It does always start with START;MEG; but sometime with little variation like START;MEG:1;   or  START;MEG:2;  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what will solve your problem 100% of the time, but it is a start:

```
((.+;){2}(([^-]*)(-.+)?;)(.+;){4}.+")
```

Group 4 contains the information you want to extract.
This is to see it working and improve it if it needs: https://regex101.com/r/6Wr1ru/1

Comment: Great. ((.*;){2}(([^-]*)(-.*)?;)(.*;){4}.*") almost close to what I needed. One more question: How do I make this expression non-greedy so that it stops at the first occurence of  ".